# jQuery Trigger Reset Only Resetting Some Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have many forms on my page that are DYNAMICALLY added and I have a button that I want to trigger a reset to all the forms on the page except one.

An example of a dynamically added form is:

```
<form>
        <label for="code">Question code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="code" name="code" maxlength="25" class="used"/>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <label for="title">Question:</label>
        <input type="text" name="titl" name="title" maxlength="255" class="used"/>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <label for="hint">Hint:</label>
        <input type="text"id="hint" name="hint" class="used"/>

        <div class="clear"></div>   

        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="tapper" class="used">
        <input type="hidden" name="optionsType" value="none" class="used">
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="delete-button">
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="action-button" onclick="pushQuestion(this);">
    </form>
```

Also, after each form is dynamically added, I call:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {e.preventDefault()});
```

Now, when I want to reset the forms, I call the following:

```
$('form').trigger('reset');
```

When entering this into the console, I get an array back with all the DOM forms. Some forms get reset, but others are unaffected. There are no errors being reported. Does anyone have any thoughts as to why some get reset while others do not?

**EDIT** Thanks for the help, but the issue has been resolved. See the problem in the comments below

Comment: Seems to work fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/5t1u337c/. Here's a more "dynamic" example: http://jsfiddle.net/5t1u337c/2/

Comment: @RyanWheale, well it took me four hours, but I figured out the problem. Because of the way I cloned the forms, it was keeping the default value as whatever was typed in the original form. Therefore, triggering a reset had no effect. To work around it, after cloning, I do a `.attr(value,'')` on each input to give it a new blank solution, and now the reset was working. It also explained why it would only happen on certain forms. Thanks for your effort though

Comment: Good to know. I guess I never assumed there was a difference between resetting and clearing. Resetting actually does just that - resets to the default values, whereas clearing requires a much more manual process of setting the values to empty. Since you discovered it, will you write an answer and accept it - explaining the difference between reset and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of tinkering, it was discovered that the issue was the result of the way the forms were cloned.

I was doing a deep clone of the existing forms which was yielding an odd state of the form which means that when `.trigger('reset')` was "triggered",  it would reset the form to the default state of the clone which may or may not have included some original data yielding a reset that did not appear to be doing anything.

A workaround was to first fire a loop over all the inputs with `.attr(value,'')` to clear the attribute value after cloning. Then the  `.trigger('reset')` functioned as expected.

Comment: You should accept this as the answer so your question doesn't sit open. Thanks for discovering this.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some inconsistencies with form handling among the various browsers. One gotcha is that the less standards-compliant browsers require an input or button with **type=submit** for some things to function correctly. I know this is that case at least with submitting a form by pressing the enter key in any text field.

Maybe try adding an **<input type='submit'/>**?